# DAX compare two years YTD

Tags: date, compare, powerbi, dax

I need to compare data from this year with the data from last year. So the customer wants to switch between full year and year-to-date comparison. The full year i already have, but with year-to-date they want to see how the are going now compared to the data from today last year e.g.:

full data from Jan 2016 - 24. Aug (today) 
 compared to Jan 2015 - 24. Aug 2015.

How to implement this in DAX? I'm using this in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a measure called [Sales], calculated from a fact table, and a Dates table, you can write 2 new measures to compare data from this year and the previous:

```
Sales YTD = CALCULATE ( [Sales]; DATESYTD ( 'Dates'[Date] ) )
```

```
Sales PY YTD = CALCULATE ( [Sales]; DATEADD ( DATESYTD ( 'Dates'[Date] ); -1; YEAR ) )
```

Putting it in a matrix visualization, it would give you the following:

[image]

Please remember to have your 'Dates' relationship to the Sales table correctly configured in order to have your time intelligence calculations done right. You can find more info [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/).